# List of all points on the edges of the image

Tags: image-processing

What is a easy and fast way to get a list of all points on the edges of the following image ?

```
img = Import["https://imgur.com/1sAtNOk.png"]
```

[image]

I tried to using the function `EdgeDetect`

```
 img = Binarize[img~ColorConvert~"Grayscale"~ImageResize~500~Blur~3]//EdgeDetect
```

[image]

but what next?

Comment: Check out [PixelValuePositions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PixelValuePositions.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
fig = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/43gUl.png"];
cm = ComponentMeasurements[Binarize@fig, "Contours"];

Graphics[{cm[[1, 2,2;;-1]]}]
```

[image]

The `cm[[1,2,2;;-1]]` contains the outer contour of apple as a `Line@{pt1,pt2,pt3,...}`